# Microsoft SQL Querying Hours in Timestamp

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I'm looking to query a Table that contains timestamps (ex: 2011-05-03 09:52:00).

Need to query the entire table and find timestamps which have been entered between 18:00:00 and 20:00:00 of any day, any month, and any year.

What is the best approach?

Thank you!

Comment: Are both sides of the range inclusive? i.e. You want timestamps >= `18:00:00` and <=`20:00:00`?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
SELECT *
    FROM YourTable
    WHERE DATEPART(hh, YourColumn) BETWEEN 18 AND 20
```

Comment: The OP wants "between 18:00:00 and 20:00:00". This would include " 20:59:59"

Answer (score 3):

This one will only get the timestamps betwee 18 and 20, including 18:00:00 and 20:00:00

```
SELECT *     
FROM YourTable     
WHERE CONVERT(varchar(8), YourDateColumn, 108)  between '18:00:00' and '20:00:00'
```

Comment: `BETWEEN` is inclusive in SQL Server so the end points will be included.

Comment: right - was an example, so if OP doesn't want 18:00 then he can do: between '18:00:01' and '19:59:59'

Comment: although it seems the first answer is already chosen (so it worked out for him :)

Comment: I was referring to the text explanation which at the moment is wrong (says "not including" rather than "including")

Answer (score 2):

For SQL Server 2008 (what the OP tagged the question as pertaining to), the obvious way is simple:

```
select *
from someTable t
where convert(time,t.dtColumn) between '18:00' and '20:00'
```

the following will work for any version of SQL Server

```
select *
from someTable t
where t.dtColumn between dateadd(hour,18,convert(datetime,convert(varchar,t.dtColumn,112),112))
                     and dateadd(hour,20,convert(datetime,convert(varchar,t.dtColumn,112),112))
```

`Between` is an inclusive test WRT to both the lower and upper bounds of the tested range. To make the test exclusive WRT to one bound or the other, you'll need something like along these lines:

```
select *
from someTable t
where convert(time,t.dtColumn) >= '18:00'
  and convert(time,t.dtColumn) <  '20:00'
```

or

```
select *
from someTable t
where t.dtColumn >= dateadd(hour,18,convert(datetime,convert(varchar,t.dtColumn,112),112))
  and t.dtColumn <  dateadd(hour,20,convert(datetime,convert(varchar,t.dtColumn,112),112))
```